# invalid relational operator error in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

i am gettng invalid relational operator in the query

```
AND CASE WHEN UPPER(TRIM(XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN.FEE_TYPE))='DEALER 
DIRECT' THEN NULL ELSE XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN.FEE_TYPE END
AND CASE WHEN UPPER(TRIM(XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN_FEE_TYPE))='DEALER 
DIRECT' THEN NULL ELSE XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN_FEE_TYPE END
```

error message:ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"

Comment: A "query" usually starts with `SELECT`.  This is not a query.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `AND` operates on `Boolean` expressions (returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`).
You apply `AND` to this expression:

```
CASE 
  WHEN UPPER(TRIM(XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN.FEE_TYPE))='DEALER DIRECT' THEN NULL 
  ELSE XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN.FEE_TYPE 
END
```

which obviously does **not** return a `Boolean` value. 
Maybe you miss something like:

```
AND CASE...END = somethingelse AND ...
```